# How to parse action data?

Tags: history

Issue on github: https://github.com/EOSIO/history-tools/issues/17

I have hex of action data. How can I understand what happened in this action? (For example: How many tokens are transferred)

```sql
   receiver   | act_account  | block_num |                          transaction_id                          | action_ordinal |                                                         act_data                                                         
--------------+--------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 eosio.token  | eosio.token  |  17833498 | 5713A31DA5EFFDAB86AB618B800B88C0115DBD9DBF5C6CFA2274CCEF0C1EF5DE |              2 | \x3042a6875e7a90c310b2b9062173b239e80300000000000004454f530000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an abi deserializer, such as abieos or eosjs.

*eosjs:*

```
const deserializedActionData = deserializeActionData(                        
            contract: "eosio.token", 
            account: "eosio.token", 
            name: "transfer", 
            data: "\x3042a6875e7a90c310b2b9062173b239e80300000000000004454f530000000000", 
            textEncoder: TextEncoder, 
            textDecoder: TextDecoder);
```

- [source](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/0187d81/src/eosjs-serialize.ts)
- [docs](https://eosio.github.io/eosjs/reference/modules/serialize.html#deserializeactiondata)